# when i create localstorage in javascript garbage values auto created

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, local-storage, garbage

When I create localstorage

```
await localStorage.setItem(item_id, JSON.stringify(products));
```

I Have garbage values `debugbar-time`, `debugbar-time-new`

I handle these garbage values like this condition's

```
if (x != 'debugbar-time-new' && x != 'debugbar-time' && x != '__mycart' && x!= 'favorite_tables')
```

But some time these values are change like `_mycart`, `favorite_tables` and I didn't use these words in my project. How can I handle these garbage values?

Comment: Data is only added to localStorage if you put it there. You need to find where/how you're adding the 'garbage' values and remove them

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(products))` might give you a clue